# distutils cpp source in side folder

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to create a setup.py script to install my module, with the sources in a non child folder. My script is pretty simple :

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension


module1 = Extension('LedPy',
                    include_dirs = ['./','../LedPrototypes','../LedPrivate','../Led','../shared/comm'],
                    libraries = ['LedConfigurator4','usb-1.0'],
                    library_dirs = ['../release'],
                    sources = ['../LedPy/LedPy.cpp', '../LedPy/LedPyDevice.cpp'],
                    extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'])

setup (name = 'LedPy',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'tbd',
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

However, when I run `python setup.py build`, the build fail because it didnt create a directory : `build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/../LedPy/LedPy.o`

Indeed, there is no temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 in the build folder. If I mkdir it manually, everything fine. And if my sources are in the same folder as the setup.py, its fine aswell.

Is it possible to have my sources in a side directory ? (my folder tree looks like this )

```
src
|-- LedPy
|   |-- LedPy.cpp
|   |-- LedPyDevice.cpp

|-- LedPyInstall
    |-- setup.py
```

Comment: I don't see how this is SCons-related.

Comment: Not related at all, I must have added it by mistake, I dont even know what SCon is

Comment: In that case: http://scons.org/  `;)`